# How to generate a Unique id, flutter

Tags: flutter, unique-id, flutter-local-notification

I am making a todo app with notifications and am using flutter local notifications plugin, How do I generate a unique integer as id for a specific todo so that I can also cancel notification of that specific todo using that unique integer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `UniqueKey().hashCode()` to get a unique `int.`
For example:

```dart
final notificationId = UniqueKey().hashCode()
// or you can use DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch
...
```

Comment: I knew Unique key wouldn't work but forgot to try hash code, thanks anyways

Answer (score 3):

I mention some of methods how you can get unique id :-

> use time stamps like this

```
DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
```

> In year 2020 you can do UniqueKey();

**Note**

A key that is only equal to itself.

This cannot be created with a const constructor because that implies that all instantiated keys would be the same instance and therefore not be unique.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/UniqueKey-class.html

> can use xid package which is lock free and has a Unicity guaranteed for 24 bits unique ids per second and per host/process

```
import 'package:xid/xid.dart';

void main() {
  var xid = Xid();
  print('generated id: $xid');

}
```

Comment: Uuid does not return an `int` as required by the flutter notifications plugin.

Comment: okay I wil update my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following class:

```
class UuidUtil {
  static int get uuid => DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch;
}
```

And access it by:

```
final id = UuidUtil.uuid;
```

Answer (score -1):

To generate a unique integer ID you can use this code

```dart
import 'package:id_gen/id_gen_helpers.dart';

final idInt = genUuid.hash();                    // 2^64 native
final idIntShort = genUuid.hash() & 0xFFFFFFFF;  // 2^32
final idIntShortest = genUuid.hash() & 0xFFFF;   // 2^16
```

from the lightweight and well-tested Dart package https://pub.dev/packages/id_gen

Answer (score -2):

You can used UUID package [here](https://pub.dev/packages/uuid)

```
import 'package:uuid/uuid.dart';

 var uuid = Uuid();
 print(uuid.v1());  

 print(uuid.v4());
```

Or refer [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/UniqueKey-class.html) also

Comment: This will not give an `int` as required by the flutter notifications plugin.

Answer (score -3):

You can use this package:
http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/uuid

```
import 'package:uuid/uuid.dart';

// Create uuid object
var uuid = Uuid();

// Generate a v1 (time-based) id
uuid.v1(); // -> '6c84fb90-12c4-11e1-840d-7b25c5ee775a'

// Generate a v4 (random) id
uuid.v4(); // -> '120ec61a-a0f2-4ac4-8393-c866d813b8d1'
```

Comment: Uuid does not return an `int` as required by the flutter notifications plugin.